# Установка Cutter (GUI для radare2). make завершается ошибкой

Tags: gui, wsl

Пытаюсь завести Gui Cutter на WSL (windows subsystem for linux).

A) Запускаю `~./Cutter-v1.6-x86_64.AppImage`

В результате ошибка:

```
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
Cannot mount AppImage, please check your FUSE setup.
You might still be able to extract the contents of this AppImage
if you run it with the --appimage-extract option.
See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE
for more information
open dir error: No such file or directory
```

B) Устанавливаю

Завершается с ошибкой:

```
g++ -rdynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/home/dmitry/miniconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/dmitry/miniconda3/lib -o Cutter Main.o Cutter.o DisassemblerGraphView.o RichTextPainter.o InitialOptionsDialog.o AboutDialog.o CommentsDialog.o EditInstructionDialog.o FlagDialog.o RenameDialog.o XrefsDialog.o MainWindow.o Helpers.o HexAsciiHighlighter.o HexHighlighter.o Highlighter.o MdHighlighter.o AsmOptionsWidget.o NewFileDialog.o AnalTask.o CommentsWidget.o ConsoleWidget.o Dashboard.o EntrypointWidget.o ExportsWidget.o FlagsWidget.o FunctionsWidget.o ImportsWidget.o Omnibar.o RelocsWidget.o SdbDock.o SectionsWidget.o Sidebar.o StringsWidget.o SymbolsWidget.o DisassemblyContextMenu.o DisassemblyWidget.o SidebarWidget.o HexdumpWidget.o Configuration.o Colors.o SaveProjectDialog.o TempConfig.o SvgIconEngine.o SyntaxHighlighter.o PseudocodeWidget.o VisualNavbar.o GraphView.o PreferencesDialog.o GeneralOptionsWidget.o GraphOptionsWidget.o PreferenceCategory.o QuickFilterView.o ClassesWidget.o ResourcesWidget.o VTablesWidget.o TypesWidget.o HeadersWidget.o SearchWidget.o CutterApplication.o JupyterConnection.o JupyterWidget.o PythonAPI.o NestedIPyKernel.o R2PluginsDialog.o CutterDockWidget.o CutterSeekableWidget.o GraphWidget.o JsonTreeItem.o JsonModel.o VersionInfoDialog.o ZignaturesWidget.o AsyncTask.o AsyncTaskDialog.o StackWidget.o RegistersWidget.o BacktraceWidget.o OpenFileDialog.o CommandTask.o ProgressIndicator.o R2Task.o DebugToolbar.o MemoryMapWidget.o DebugOptionsWidget.o BreakpointWidget.o BreakpointsDialog.o AttachProcDialog.o RegisterRefsWidget.o SetToDataDialog.o qrc_resources.o qrc_style.o moc_Cutter.o moc_DisassemblerGraphView.o moc_CachedFontMetrics.o moc_AboutDialog.o moc_AsmOptionsWidget.o moc_CommentsDialog.o moc_EditInstructionDialog.o moc_FlagDialog.o moc_RenameDialog.o moc_XrefsDialog.o moc_HexAsciiHighlighter.o moc_HexHighlighter.o moc_MainWindow.o moc_Highlighter.o moc_MdHighlighter.o moc_InitialOptionsDialog.o moc_NewFileDialog.o moc_AnalTask.o moc_CommentsWidget.o moc_ConsoleWidget.o moc_Dashboard.o moc_EntrypointWidget.o moc_ExportsWidget.o moc_FlagsWidget.o moc_FunctionsWidget.o moc_ImportsWidget.o moc_Omnibar.o moc_RelocsWidget.o moc_SdbDock.o moc_SectionsWidget.o moc_Sidebar.o moc_StringsWidget.o moc_SymbolsWidget.o moc_DisassemblyContextMenu.o moc_DisassemblyWidget.o moc_SidebarWidget.o moc_HexdumpWidget.o moc_Configuration.o moc_SaveProjectDialog.o moc_SyntaxHighlighter.o moc_PseudocodeWidget.o moc_VisualNavbar.o moc_GraphView.o moc_PreferencesDialog.o moc_GeneralOptionsWidget.o moc_GraphOptionsWidget.o moc_QuickFilterView.o moc_ClassesWidget.o moc_ResourcesWidget.o moc_CutterApplication.o moc_VTablesWidget.o moc_TypesWidget.o moc_HeadersWidget.o moc_SearchWidget.o moc_JupyterConnection.o moc_JupyterWidget.o moc_R2PluginsDialog.o moc_CutterDockWidget.o moc_CutterSeekableWidget.o moc_GraphWidget.o moc_VersionInfoDialog.o moc_ZignaturesWidget.o moc_AsyncTask.o moc_AsyncTaskDialog.o moc_StackWidget.o moc_RegistersWidget.o moc_BacktraceWidget.o moc_OpenFileDialog.o moc_StringsTask.o moc_FunctionsTask.o moc_CommandTask.o moc_R2Task.o moc_DebugToolbar.o moc_MemoryMapWidget.o moc_DebugOptionsWidget.o moc_BreakpointWidget.o moc_BreakpointsDialog.o moc_AttachProcDialog.o moc_RegisterRefsWidget.o moc_SetToDataDialog.o   -lr_core -lcapstone -lr_config -lr_debug -lr_bin -lr_anal -lr_bp -lr_egg -lr_asm -lr_lang -lr_parse -lr_flag -lr_cons -lr_reg -lr_search -lr_syscall -lr_fs -lr_io -lr_socket -lr_magic -lmagic -lr_crypto -lr_hash -lr_util -lz -lzip -ldl -lpython3.6m -L/home/dmitry/miniconda3/lib -lQt5Svg -lQt5WebEngineWidgets -lQt5PrintSupport -lQt5Widgets -lQt5WebEngineCore -lQt5Quick -lQt5Gui -lQt5WebChannel -lQt5Qml -lQt5Network -lQt5Positioning -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread

/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lzip
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:764: recipe for target 'Cutter' failed
make: *** [Cutter] Error 1
```

Собственно вопрос: как запустить Cutter?

Comment: Сильно не уверен что там есть в наличии `fuse`, это часть кернеля, смотрите MS документацию,поддерживает ли оно это. А проще попробовать в командной строке выполнить `modprobe fuse` и посмотреть что ответит.

Comment: modprobe fuse
    modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open 
    moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.0-17134-Microsoft/modules.dep.bin'
    modprobe: FATAL: Module fuse not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-17134-Microsoft

Comment: Так и я предположил что его там нет. Кернел должен быть собран с поддержкой `fuse`, это же микрософт, там все обычно кастрированное и извращённое :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Подсказка была в вопросе.

```
./Cutter-v1.6-x86_64.AppImage --appimage-extract 
cd squashfs-root
./AppRun
```

Запустилось:)